# Accessing user information from LinkedIn on login

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I want to provide a "Login with LinkedIn" functionality for my web application.When the user logs in, I want to request him to share specific information about his LinkedIn profile(eg. personal details, member of which groups, posts on linkedIn, etc )  as I want to read that information and build some recommendations based on that. However, I do not know what all information can be had from this LinkedIn for that user. Can you please point me to some code/docs that help me do this.

Thanks
kabir

Answer (score 1):

The https://developer.linkedin.com website would be a good start.  You can walk through authorizing the user by following the steps found at:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

Additionally, the list of fields available to you can be found here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile